# LG 5k display as docking station for multiple MacBooks

Tags: display, hardware, thunderbolt-display

Is it possible to connect an Apple mouse and keyboard to the [LG UltraFine 5k display](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKN62LL/A/lg-ultrafine-5k-display) via Bluetooth, and then interchangeably connect separate MacBook Pro's to the display without have to reconnect the keyboard and mouse to them?

I have separate MacBook Pro's for personal and work, and I'm hoping the display itself can serve as a docking station. As soon as I connect the computer to the display via Thunderbolt, I'm hoping that the keyboard and mouse are automatically able to control the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### LG Display has no bluetooth

The LG UltraFine 5K Display has no bluetooth connectivity. Thus you cannot connect bluetooth peripherals to it.

### Pairing the mouse/keyboard

You can connect an Apple Magic Mouse 2 and Apple Magic Keyboard to a MacBook via Bluetooth and/or using a Lightning cable.

You may need to buy a USB-A to USB-C adapter to connect them.

### A possible solution

Both devices need to paired every time you want to use them with different computers/MacBooks. You can, however, leave the Lightning cables attached. If they are connected to a MacBook running macOS 10.12 or later they will pair instantly it. After that you may disconnect the cable or leave it attached (keyboard/trackpad only).

- Connect the keyboard and mouse using the Lightning cable to a display with a USB-C Dock
- Connect the display and your MacBook using a USB-C cable

If you choose to replace the Magic Mouse 2 with a Magic Trackpad you may leave the cables attached all the time.

Comment: Don't know why I thought the LG monitor had Bluetooth connectivity...